# Script MySQL procedure error

Tags: mysql

Hola estoy realizando un ejercicio de clase tengo que saber el usuario con el que estoy conectado.
El problema esta en que no me funciona

```
# Hacer un procedimiento llamado userActual que cada vez que es llamado muestre 
# el nombre del usuario actual y su ubicacion (Este procedimiento no es necesitaria 
# parametros),El mensaje es similar a  : 
# El usuario pepito se ha  conectado desde localhost

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS userActual $$
CREATE PROCEDURE userActual();
BEGIN
        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error.

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
BEGIN
                SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1);
END' at line 1
```

Solo quiero el error que tengo no el ejercicio que ya mas o menos tengo una idea.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucinado :

```
# Hacer un procedimiento llamado userActual que cada vez que es llamado muestre 
# el nombre del usuario actual y su ubicacion (Este procedimiento no es necesitaria 
# parametros),El mensaje es similar a  : 
# El usuario pepito se ha  conectado desde localhost
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS userActual $$
CREATE PROCEDURE userActual()
BEGIN
        SELECT CONCAT('El usuario ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1), ' se ha conectado desde ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', -1)) 'TU USUARIO ES : ';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Puse ; en la linea de create procedure